# How to reverse an infinate animation in Web Animation API?

Tags: javascript, css, web-animations, web-animations-api

In [Web Animation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API), we can animate elements by [Element.animate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate) interface. The returned [Animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation) object can be played, paused or reversed by `.play()`, `.pause()` and `.reverse()`.

```js
let img = document.querySelector('#happy-boy');

const boy_animation = [
    { transform: 'rotate(0)' },
    { transform: 'rotate(360deg)' },
];
const boy_timing = {
    duration: 3000,
    iterations: Infinity,
}

let animation = img.animate(boy_animation, boy_timing);
animation.reverse(); // <-- fails with DOM exception
```

I get this error when i try to reverse() the animation:

> `Cannot play reversed Animation with infinite target effect end.`

[image: chrome 86 on Linux]

Comment: It's telling you that you can reverse the animation, but you can't loop it in reverse if the target count is `Infinity`. A workaround can be to set an arbitrarily large number instead such as `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of `reverse()`, like `play()`, is that if the animation is at the "end", it jumps back to the start and begins playing.

For `reverse()` this means that if the current time is zero when you call it (as in your example), then it should jump back to the beginning. However, if your animation has an infinite length, that would mean jumping to infinity!

If you simply want to run the animation's keyframes backwards, you can use the [`direction`](https://drafts.csswg.org/web-animations-1/#dom-effecttiming-direction) property.

For example:

```
animation.effect.updateTiming({ direction: 'reverse' });
```

Note, however, that unlike `reverse()`, updating the direction while an animation is in progress can cause it to jump position.

If you want to be able to change the animation direction backwards and forwards *while* it is in progress *and* make it repeat forever, you can either:

1. Set a very long iteration count and start the animation in the middle of that range, or
2. Use `updateTiming({ direction: 'reverse' })` and adjust the `currentTime` so that it doesn't jump. Something like the following might work:

   ```
    const ct = animation.effect.getComputedTiming();
    animation.currentTime =
        ct.currentInteration * ct.duration +
        (ct.duration - ct.localTime % ct.duration);
   ```

Note further that even using `updateTiming` as in (2) can cause the animation to jump a little if the animation is running asynchronously (e.g. most transform and opacity animations) since there can be some small lag between the timing on the main thread where your Javascript runs and the thread/process where the animation is being run.

Using `reverse()` as in (1) (or `updatePlaybackRate()`) avoids that problem since it synchronizes any async animations before updating them.